# Why does remove duplicates now throws an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I had a script working about a month ago and nothing has changed since. However, when I run the script now, it throws an error. The function I am trying to use is the `Remove Duplicates` function.

I've tried changing the function in multiple ways thinking that it may be the order, however, I cannot work out how it has broken since nothing has changed since it last worked.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$8000").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
```

As stated, the expected result is that it removes all the duplicates at the end since the previous part of the script is removing a wide criteria.

Error message:

[image: Error Message]

Data example and the highlight of what should be removed:

[image]

Test example which also failed on me which was a lot smaller:

[image]

EDIT

Found the issue now... the data was in a separate table within excel so I just copied it out and pasted it as values in a separate sheet.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I tried the line.. It's working fine.

Comment: Can you post a data example of where are you aplying this?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an edit to the question, however I'll post it here to close the question. The table was imported to excel as an XML and had stayed in that format, hence the function wasn't working properly. To fix it, all I had to do was copy all the data and paste it into a separate sheet as values.